# wordpress enqueues some scripts and leaves other

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the function below to register and enqueue scripts in my function.php file. The problem is ONLY one script (custom.js) doesn't seem to enqueue....when I view the source of my page here: http://dev1.envisionwebdesign.co/features/ custom.js is not loaded. Any thoughts?

```
function register_my_scripts() { 
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),null, true );
wp_register_script( 'nicescroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),null, true );
wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery','nicescroll' ),null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'nicescroll' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' ); 
 }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' );
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
```

Comment: Ahhhh sometimes it's right in front of you. Thanks :)